# terraform: apply dynamic disks differently if name match expression

Tags: loops, dynamic, terraform

Have to deploy couple of rancher clusters on vsphere

**code snippet terraform.tfvars**

i have also 2 lists :

```
master_nodes = [“master101”,“master102”,“master103”]

worker_nodes = [“worker101”,“worker102”,“worker103”,“worker104”,“worker105”,“worker106”]

master_disks = [
  {
    number = 1
    size   = 60
  }
]

worker_disks = [
  {
    number = 1
    size   = 100
  },
  {
    number = 2
    size   = 350
  }
]
```

**main.tf**

```
dynamic "disk" {
  for_each = [
    for d in var.worker_disks : d
    if length(regexall("worker.*", each.value.name)) > 0
  ]
  content {
    label       = "disk${disk.value["number"]}"
    size        = disk.value["size"]
    unit_number = disk.value["number"]
  }
}
```

The above code works flawless adding dynamic disks for worker nodes.

But, what I can't figure out is: for each master node add one disk, for each worker node add 2 or more disks

```
[root@dev-vm1011 terraform_k8s]# ./terraform console
> local.cluster_nodes
{
  "master_nodes-master_vm1" = {
    "name" = "master101"
    "node_key" = "master_nodes"
    "sub_node_key" = "master_vm1"
    "vcpu" = ""
    "vm_ip" = "192.168.50.66"
  }
  "master_nodes-master_vm2" = {
    "name" = "master102"
    "node_key" = "master_nodes"
    "sub_node_key" = "master_vm2"
    "vcpu" = ""
    "vm_ip" = "192.168.50.77"
  }
  "master_nodes-master_vm3" = {
    "name" = "master103"
    "node_key" = "master_nodes"
    "sub_node_key" = "master_vm3"
    "vcpu" = ""
    "vm_ip" = "192.168.50.88"
  }
  "worker_nodes-worker_vm1" = {
    "name" = "worker101"
    "node_key" = "worker_nodes"
    "sub_node_key" = "worker_vm1"
    "vcpu" = "4"
    "vm_ip" = "192.168.50.99"
  }
  "worker_nodes-worker_vm2" = {
    "name" = "worker102"
    "node_key" = "worker_nodes"
    "sub_node_key" = "worker_vm2"
    "vcpu" = "4"
    "vm_ip" = "192.168.50.103"
  }
  "worker_nodes-worker_vm3" = {
    "name" = "worker103"
    "node_key" = "worker_nodes"
    "sub_node_key" = "worker_vm3"
    "vcpu" = "2"
    "vm_ip" = "192.168.50.104"
  }
}
```

particularly :

```
  for d in var.worker_disks : d
    if length(regexall("worker.*", each.value.name)) > 0
```

Using this part of the code to apply dynamic disks to worker nodes (hostname match ~worker)

Last resort is just to tune template image from where the machines are cloned, but the idea is to apply dynamic disk block based on hostname match condition.
Is like I need to apply a second dynamic disk block if name ~master.*

Comment: I don't understand... you say the code works for the worker nodes, those are the ones that have 2 or more disks, why would that same logic not work for master?

Comment: Would be better if you can share the entire TF code for your issue instead of just the dynamic block snippet